# how to email form on submit using zend_form?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

OK.  I finally got my zend form working, validating, filtering and sending the contents to my process page (by using `$form->populate($formData);`)

Now, how do I email myself the contents of a form when submitted?  Is this a part of Zend_form or some other area I need to be looking in?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Zend Mail for this, Zend form does not offer such functions.. but its an nice idea.

In your controleller, after $form->isValid();

```
if ($form->isValid($_POST)) {
 $mail = new Zend_Mail();
 $values = $form->getValues();
 $mailText = 'My form valueS: ';

  foreach ($values as $v) {
    $mailText .= 'Value ' . $v . PHP_EOL;
      }

 $mail->setFrom('user@user.de', 'user');
 $mail->AddTo('Me@me.de', 'me');
 $mail->setSubject->$form->getName();
 $mail->send();
} else {
    // what ever
}
```